# Print Functionality in Salesforce1 Mobile App

Tags: javascript, salesforce1-app, html5, canvas

I am trying to do the print option in the Salesforce1 Mobile app. I have tried two methods of printing, one is a Javascript method and the other I've tried using is the canvas method. But both methods are not working. Can anyone advise me on how to do this? I'm using an Apple iPad.

### Javascript Method:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function printDiv(divID) {
            //Get the HTML of div
            var divElements = document.getElementById(divID).innerHTML;
            //Get the HTML of whole page
            var oldPage = document.body.innerHTML;

            //Reset the page's HTML with div's HTML only
            document.body.innerHTML = 
              "<html><head><title></title></head><body>" + 
              divElements + "</body>";

            //Print Page
            window.print();

            //Restore orignal HTML
            document.body.innerHTML = oldPage;
        }
    </script>
      <input type="button" value="Print" onclick="javascript:printDiv('printablediv')" style="width:80px; height:50;font-size: 18px; "/>
<div id="printablediv">
Text Here
 </div>
```

### HTML5 Method:

```
 <script>
    function printCanvas(el)  
    {  
        var dataUrl = document.getElementById(el).toDataURL(); //attempt to save base64 string to server using this var  
        var windowContent = '<!DOCTYPE html>';
        windowContent += '<html>'
        windowContent += '<head><title>Print canvas</title></head>';
        windowContent += '<body>'
        windowContent += '<img src="' + dataUrl + '">';
        windowContent += '</body>';
        windowContent += '</html>';
        var printWin = window.open('','','width=340,height=260');
        printWin.document.open();
        printWin.document.write(windowContent);
        printWin.document.close();
        printWin.focus();
        printWin.print();
        //printWin.close();
    } 
</script>
<style type="text/css">
    canvas {
        outline: 1px solid #999;
    }
    </style>
    <div>
        <canvas id="mycanvas" width="320" height="240">
            Your browser does not support the canvas element.
        </canvas>
        <button onclick="printCanvas('mycanvas')">Print</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: "Not working" -- what is happening? What else have you tried? Are you getting a JS error?

Comment: I am facing the same issue. My code with window.print(); is working perfectly in browser but not in salesforce1. It doesn't show any error as well.